# Procurar um valor em determinada coluna em um arquivo.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer a pesquisa de um valor em determinada posição na coluna de um arquivo de texto e gerando outro arquivo com essas linhas, mas sem êxito

Segue o código:

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
arquivo2 = open('arquivo2.txt', 'w')

for i in arquivo.readlines():
    if i[70:71] == '02':
        arquivo2.write(i)
        print(i.rstrip())



arquivo.close()
arquivo2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou você falar o que acontece quando você roda, se dá erro, ou se tem algum outro problema no resultado.

Como nós não temos o arquivo, só você, não tem como adivinhar o que está acontecendo.

Um dos erros que já dá pra perceber é que você faz a comparação `i[70:71] == '02'` porém `i[70:71]` possui **somente 1 caracter** logo nunca pode ser igual a `'02'`.

Talvez você queira dizer `i[70:72]` ou `i[69:71]` pois estes tem 2 caracteres.

Comment: Realmente era apenas esse detalhe na posição da coluna! E não gerava erro nenhum, apenas o arquivo vazio, mais deu certo ajustando a posição. Obrigado!